# Succession war to topple an Elective Monarchy?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

So, through a bit of luck, predatory big powers, thirst for conquest, and murdering my way down a family tree, I find myself 3rd in line to the throne of a Kingdom with an elective monarchy.

I have one duchy in the de jure kingdom, which allowed me to vote for a successor, and I voted for myself. This left me about 4th in line, so I began throwing people off castles, apparently.

The original strategy was to get myself elected king - either by murdering everyone else in the way, or getting another duchy (which I'm close to) and rising to power that way.

However, it occurs to me that pretenders to the throne can start a succession war once the king dies. (Until like 5 years after) Does any one know if this works for an elective monarchy? Also, any tips or alternative suggestions?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't think elective allows for pretender succession wars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you can't launch a succession war, apparently. Just not possible. Which makes sense, as the point of elective is that it's "Fair" and the result shouldn't be disputed.

However, I kept murdering my way down the line, and it all worked out.I didn't even have to get that second duchy, although, to be fair, doing so would have saved about 5 lives. Oh well.

I think the opinion destabilization for all the candidate dukes may have been more important than the deaths, but it worked anyway. It probably couldn't hurt to bribe anyone who has a fairly high opinion of you initially too.

As a side note, for anyone who wants to try this, I immediately destroyed the kingdom and recreated it - which gave it the same crown authority and succession laws (Primogeniture) as my primary title, saving me the trouble of worrying about succession.

Comment: Didn't destroying it give a huge negative opinion towards you? And, more importantly, doing so didn't you lose kingdom's vassals?